# Good shopping cart gem for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, shopping-cart

I need to add some functions to my app-catalog of car spare parts. I see a lot of questions on so as my. But main difference is, that i don't need something like spree gem, that also build catalog... I need to add only to my catalog shopping cart (add to cart, cart, order). Are there any good solutions? Simple cart (without e-pay systems etc)??? Becouse spree is to hard to customize (i will say to more simple it)

Comment: I'd check out https://github.com/kopfmaschine/shop-bunny or https://github.com/crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart

Comment: @JesseWolgamott  maybe good... will check, but also it is answer, not a comment

Comment: Yep --- I think you should check out what's out there before this can be answered. It's a vague question, so you need to do some research first.

Comment: hm... it could take i while... becouse i went now to holidays for some time...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use the Saas product [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/), it is best.